# Calculate the number of equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and let $B = \{1,2,3\}$

Let $R$ be a relation such that $R=\{(x,y) \in P(A) \times P(A): x \cap B = y\cap B\}$

How many equivalence classes are possible?

I'm kinda stuck at this problem... can't seem to visualize this or find the correct path to calculate this.

Some help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\cap B$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ has $8$ subsets. For each of these subsets there is one equivalence class. So the required number is $8$.